# I get this error: IndexError: too many indices

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

the function Gini define below is giving me some problem. I suspect that the problem is in the shape of my data passed to it, however, I was not able to fix it. 
this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/LibertyMutual2015/Aug2_MWE.py", line 63, in <module>
    mse.append(Gini(test_fold.target, pred))
  File "/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/LibertyMutual2015/Aug2_MWE.py", line 18, in Gini
    true_order = arr[arr[:,0].argsort()][::-1,0]
IndexError: too many indices
```

this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.cross_validation import *
import random

def Gini(y_true, y_pred):
    # check and get number of samples
    assert y_true.shape == y_pred.shape
    n_samples = y_true.shape[0]

    # sort rows on prediction column 
    # (from largest to smallest)
    arr = np.array([y_true, y_pred]).transpose()
    true_order = arr[arr[:,0].argsort()][::-1,0]
    pred_order = arr[arr[:,1].argsort()][::-1,0]

    # get Lorenz curves
    L_true = np.cumsum(true_order) / np.sum(true_order)
    L_pred = np.cumsum(pred_order) / np.sum(pred_order)
    L_ones = np.linspace(0, 1, n_samples)

    # get Gini coefficients (area between curves)
    G_true = np.sum(L_ones - L_true)
    G_pred = np.sum(L_ones - L_pred)

    # normalize to true Gini coefficient
    return G_pred/G_true


features = np.random.randint(0,10,size=[100,5])
target = np.random.randint(0,2,size=100)

df = DataFrame(features)
df['target'] = target
#print df.head()

kf = KFold(df.shape[0], n_folds=10)
mse = []
fold_count = 0
for train, test in kf:
    print("Processing fold %s" % fold_count)
    train_fold = df.ix[train]
    test_fold = df.ix[test]

    features = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['target']]

    # Get training examples
    train_fold_input = train_fold[features].values
    train_fold_output = train_fold['target']

    # Fit RandomForest 
    cfr = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, n_jobs = -1)
    cfr.fit(train_fold_input, train_fold_output)

    # Check MSE on test set
    pred = cfr.predict(test_fold[features])
    print test_fold.target
    print pred
    mse.append(Gini(test_fold.target, pred))

    # Done with the fold
    fold_count += 1
```

Comment: This code ran fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want an extra `,:` in your indexing on that line and the next?

```
true_order = arr[arr[:,0].argsort() ,: ][::-1,0]
pred_order = arr[arr[:,1].argsort() ,: ][::-1,0]
```